# Using jQuery removeAttr on an input button

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm currently trying to remove the value text which shows on one of my buttons as I am now using an image in it's place. I have tried using the removeAttr function in jQuery but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there something I have missed?

```
$('div.widget-container > div.search > form.search > div#search_links > input.button').removeAttr("value");
```

Comment: are u sure you're selecting it right? care to share the html with us here also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` is a property and you cannot remove it entirely, you can set it's value as an empty string:

```
$('#search_links > input.button').val('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show fragment of HTML code with this button.

Now it like as you use wrong selector in jQuery for access to button.

Answer (score 0):

The value attribute maps to `defaultValue` property, there is no corresponding attribute for the `value` property, so you must use `.val("")` or `.prop( "value", "" )`

Answer (score 0):

it is better and faster if you define a class or id for your element and then select that :
so if you want to use removeAttr to remove value of an input element i suggest to set value to empty :

```
$('#yourinputid').val('');
```

or if you want to remove something else :

```
$('#yourinputid').removeAttr('class'); # or disabled or id or other attrs ;
```

Comment: I am aware of this but as it's a closed system that outputs html from a database I don't have much control over the underlying css and existing classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on IE, it's a known bug : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11598

Try this instead :

```
$('div.widget-container > div.search > form.search > div#search_links > input.button').val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Having only **one** ID element as selector is faster that nesting 100's of them :)

```
$('#search_links').find('input.button').prop('value', '');
```

Comment: The problem is our system outputs multiple fields in this way with the same id and class therefore I have to nest 100s of them for it to work in our system. It has to be very specific.

Comment: @jme1988 ok, if your system outputs same-named multiple ID elements, that's a good job?

Comment: Well a number of the elements don't actually have ids hence why I am have to reference them in such a nested way referring to classes and what not. My team are database specialists and their product is built from the database mainly. I'm new to the company and realize that some things like this should be changed however I have to work with the system as it is at the moment. It's a successful systems used by many big name clients so must be a good job!

Answer (score 0):

empty the value of text

```
$('div#search_links > input.button').val('');
```